# How can keep no but not no. during the time of removing english stopwords using R

Tags: r

I have a sentence:

```
No display on my system asset no. 12rrtyght123
```

here no. means number.

When I am using stopword remove code in R all "no" is getting removed.
But I want to keep the initial "No".
How can I do that?

Comment: Are you working with the `tm` package? If so please update your question to include that, and the `stopwords` code that's giving you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I really understand the question, but you may want `sub`

```
> x <- "No display on my system asset no. 12rrtyght123"
> sub("no. ", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "No display on my system asset 12rrtyght123"
```

It seems like you may be working with the `tm` package.  If so, please update the question accordingly.